# Simulate radiation on a body in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I have an Operating Room scene with a patient and an X-Ray device. The device shows the Patiens X-Ray in a canvas with a Camera and some shader Graph. What I want to do next is to show how much radiation the part of the body is taking by coloring the body from Green to Red, depending on the intensity and time exposed to the Ray Area.
I want the body to slowly start becoming red in the affected area and when not affected, slowly turn green again.
I tried to have that effect using shadergraph but is looks like a flashlight is moving across a body and does not have the desired effect. Does anyone have ideas or recommendation or Assets that could acieve this?
Project is using URP Unity 2021.3 WebGL build
Thank you

I tried to have that effect using shadergraph but is looks like a flashlight is moving across a body and does not have the desired effect. It goes red instantly and follows the ray. Unaffected area turns green immediatly.

Comment: Im not a shader expert but look up heatmaps and consider dividing body surface into little squares and setting colours by values of the heatmap

Comment: How does your shader work right now? Please also take a screen shot of the effect and an edited mockup for how it should look.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.